# Do I keep PS Plus games with a new Plus account when the old one expires?

Tags: playstation-plus

I was initially using my cousin's PS Plus account on my Ps4. Now, I'm thinking of getting my own. My question is, will I be able to play the free games I downloaded via his account with my new PS Plus account when his eventually expires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only play the free games you collected with your own account!

Comment: rolled back because missed the word collected here.. sorry sime

Comment: @Nitro.de no problem, everybody makes mistakes :)

Comment: to provide further understanding, these games are made "free" for that period of time. And when you first download them, you are purchasing them to your account. You don't pay, but it is still classed as a transaction. The same rules apply as to games you **do** pay for. Your new account will not register the game as being purchased, which is why you can not play it, even if the game is installed on your console.